# How to skip the last string elements in the loop?

Tags: rust

How to skip the last string elements in the loop?

My solution is working fine

```
fn main() {
    let s = "123456".to_string();
    for ch in (&s[..s.len()-1]).chars() { // skip the last element
        println!("{}", ch);
    }
}
```

But is there something better?

Similar to `skip()` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip
that allows to skip first elements in the loop

Comment: Your solution will fail horribly if the final character in your string is not ASCII, as your slice will cut it in two, and the attempt to convert it to a character will fail the UTF-8 self-checking.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Just tried it, `for ch in s.chars().rev().skip(1).rev() {` would require `Chars` to implement `ExactSizeIterator`, which, due to the nature of UTF-8 variable-width characters, it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`next_back` (from the `DoubleEndedIterator` trait)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html#tymethod.next_back) to explicitly remove the final character before beginning iteration:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "123456".to_string();
    let mut chars = s.chars();  // Create mutable iterator
    chars.next_back();          // Discard last element
    for ch in chars {           // Iterate the rest
        println!("{}", ch);
    }
}
```

If you need to remove multiple characters, just run `next_back` in a simple range loop (possibly checking for `None` to allow you to `break` immediately if you try to skip more characters than exist).

[As I noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705923/how-to-skip-the-last-string-elements-in-the-loop/77705961#comment136993346_77705923), your solution is not safe in the presence of UTF-8 characters, as it could slice in-between the bytes of a single UTF-8 character. This solution *is* safe, as `next_back` will decode and omit a UTF-8 character of any width properly.

---

The reason you can't do something like this without operating from the back forward first, is that variable-width UTF-8 characters mean that operating purely in forward order, Rust has no idea when it's `x` characters from the end of the string until it *reaches* the end of the string (at which point it could know only in hindsight). Even when it knows it's four bytes from the end, it could be 1 (single four byte character), 2 (two two-byte characters), 3 (two singles and a two-byte), or 4 (four singles) characters in that range, and it must decode to figure out which scenario it is in. Only `ExactSizeIterator`s, which know their precise length up front, can do this with clever use of `rev` and `skip`, [a `DoubleEndedIterator`, which is what `.chars()` gives you, cannot.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da071152536721a916fb3121796698cb)

Comment: @user2722968: That will not work, as I specifically indicated in the answer, because `.chars()` only give you a `DoubleEndedIterator`, not an `ExactSizeIterator`, and that trick requires `ExactSizeIterator`. [I already tried it on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da071152536721a916fb3121796698cb), just to be sure. You could do it with `.bytes()`, which is an `ExactSizeIterator`, but not with `.chars()`. If you *know* the string is ASCII, you could then cast the `u8`s back to `char` and it would work, but now you've broken Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Because `.len()` on a string returns the number of bytes, not the number of chars, your attempt will fail with multi-byte chars.

Here is a suggestion: just delay the printing.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "1é2è3ç4•".to_string();
    let mut chars = s.chars();
    if let Some(mut prev) = chars.next() {
        for ch in chars {
            print!("{} ", prev);
            prev = ch;
        }
        println!();
    }
}
/*
1 é 2 è 3 ç 4
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `peekable()` to stop printing as soon as the next character is the last one, that is when `peek()` doesn't see another character to come:

```
let s = "12345ඞ".to_string();
let mut it = s.chars().peekable();
while let Some(ch) = it.next() {
    if it.peek().is_some() {  // skip None
        println!("{ch}");
    }
}
```

*Can handle Unicode characters.*
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=75ae07d86d3c57156b7eece388ba31b6)